# Configure RabbitMQ to route to queue via HTTP endpoint, therefore not needing the normal JSON data

Tags: api, http, rabbitmq

For my deployment I have a number of 3rd party systems that can only send HTTP POST requests with metrics (I need in the queue) and they cannot be re-configured. My goal is to have specific endpoints (or vhosts) that when POST'd to will automatically route to the correct queue, without needing the necessary routing key and other standard rabbitmq JSON data. As this modification is not possible in the 3rd party systems.

I can't find any way to do this natively as of now, but I believe it may be possible to configure a HTTP reverse proxy in the front, whereby any data sent to the specific endpoint, will be re-directed to the correct rabbitMQ HTTP endpoint, where I could then bolt in the nessary JSON data so it can be parsed by rabbitmq and placed in the realvent queue. I wanted to check if this is the only logical solution to this, or am I missing something obvious that can be done within rabbitmq's administration page or via config files.

Comment: Have you checked the RabbitMQ HTTP API's , not sure how easy it will be configure the reverse proxy but worth a try

Comment: This is my intention, however I wasn't sure if there may be a way to achieve this natively? Without any additional services to be wrapped around the front end of Rabbit. Any ideas?